# Hide keyboard from within a fragment

Tags: android, keyboard, fragment, hide

I try to hide the keyboard from within a fragment. The fragment is inside a viewpager.

I use this code, which works fine when running on Android emulator.

```
 View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

On a huawei mate 20 pro device **view is always null**.

How can I get this working on every device?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling `requestFocus()` on the edittext before hiding the keyboard.

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.notes_edittext).requestFocus();

View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Maybe its helpfull to someone else.